# Understanding AutoFac Captive-dependencies

Tags: c#, autofac

Forgive me I am just a newbie for `AutoFac`, I just began to learn to how it works. I have some problems to understand the `Captive-dependencies` and sope `Lifetime` when I read the [Captive-Dependencies](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/captive-dependencies.html) in the official site.

What make me confused is the example mentioned in the post. Please kindly review the comments below. Thanks.

The original explain looks like blew. I just quoted it here.

```
public class RuleManager
{
  public RuleManager(IEnumerable<IRule> rules)
  {
      this.Rules = rules;
  }

  public IEnumerable<IRule> Rules { get; private set; }
}

public interface IRule { }

public class SingletonRule : IRule { }

public class InstancePerDependencyRule : IRule { }


[Fact]
public void CaptiveDependency()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    // The rule manager is a single-instance component. It
    // will only ever be instantiated one time and the cached
    // instance will be used thereafter. It will be always be resolved
    // from the root lifetime scope (the container) because
    // it needs to be shared.
    builder.RegisterType<RuleManager>()
           .SingleInstance();

    // This rule is registered instance-per-dependency. A new
    // instance will be created every time it's requested.
    builder.RegisterType<InstancePerDependencyRule>()
           .As<IRule>();

    // This rule is registered as a singleton. Like the rule manager
    // it will only ever be resolved one time and will be resolved
    // from the root lifetime scope.
    builder.RegisterType<SingletonRule>()
           .As<IRule>()
           .SingleInstance();

    using (var container = builder.Build())
    using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope("request"))
    {
      // The manager will be a singleton. It will contain
      // a reference to the singleton SingletonRule, which is
      // fine. However, it will also hold onto an InstancePerDependencyRule
      // which may not be OK. The InstancePerDependencyRule that it
      // holds will live for the lifetime of the container inside the
      // RuleManager and will last until the container is disposed.
      var manager = scope.Resolve<RuleManager>();
    }
}
```

After reading it I have some questions and understanding which shows below. Please help to review it.

1. When the lifetime of scope(container.BeginLifetimeScope("request")) is over when the `using` statement is finished, Which instance of component will be disposable? `InstancePerDependencyRule` or `RuleManager`?

My answer is `InstancePerDependencyRule` will be disposable. Is it right? The reason show in the 2.

2. Why the `InstancePerDependencyRule` lifetime is longer than the `Rulemanger`? and the example said it is against `Captive-dependencies` rule. Please help to explain it more exactly. In my understanding it is registered as `Instance-per-dependency` by default. it will be disposable after the scope(container.BeginLifetimeScope("request")) is over. (because It is wrapped by a using statement). I think the `InstancePerDependencyRule` lifetime should be shorter than the `RuleManger` which is `Singleton`.

Please help to correct me if there is anything wrong in my understanding. Thanks.

Comment: Joe.wang did you get the answer?